# AngularJs $transclude - How to access the html content of clone object?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to acccess the content of the 'clone' object inside of a $transclude function in a directive, but clone.html() returns undefined. How do I access the html content of the directive element / clone ?

```
.directive('somedirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA'
        , replace: true
        , transclude: true
        , scope: true
         , controller: function ($scope, $element, $transclude, $log) {
             $transclude(function (clone) {
                 console.log(clone.html()); //undefined??
                 console.log(clone.text()); //works but strips the html tags
                 // How do I access the html content of clone???
                })
             }
         }
```

[**SEE PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/8jJI7iIW59N4NKtHwwRb?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You were getting undefined because your clone is actually three elements, text-div-text. So, removing the whitespace between `<drt> and <div>` fixes part of the problem, so "clone.html()" will then print "testing".  The second part of the problem, is that .html() uses the "innerHTML" property, so it won't include the root DOM element of clone.  Instead, try using `clone[0].outerHTML` or `angular.element("<div/>").append(clone).html()`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/mOnlFLJMHkQ0iQIeZTwd?p=preview

```
controller: function($scope, $element, $transclude, $log){
 $transclude(function(clone) {
     console.log(clone[0].innerHTML); //undefined??
     console.log(clone[0].outerHTML); //undefined??
     console.log(angular.element("<div/>").append(clone).html()); //undefined??
     console.log(clone.text()); //works but strips the html tags    
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use following code to convert an element to a plain HTML:

```
var transcludedHtml = "";  // this var accumulates a result
$transclude(function(clone) {
  clone.each(function(idx, node) {
    if (node.outerHTML) {
      transcludedHtml += node.outerHTML;
    }
  });
```

The method is not perfect as it skips nodes of some types (e.g. HTML entities   etc.). But for regular HTML snippets with tag elements it is good enough.